# If I hide a text input element with javascript can other javascript functions still access a value entered into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use this function:

```
function storagecalc(){
var thediv=document.forms["boxes"];
var boxno=thediv.elements["numbofboxes"];
var howmany =0;    //If the textbox is not blank    */
if(boxno.value!="")    
{        
howmany=parseInt(quantity.value);    
}
return howmany;
document.getElementById('numberprice').innerHTML = "£"+howmany;
}
```

To grab a value entered here:

```
<form action="" id="boxes">

<input type="text" id="numbofboxes" value="" name="boxnumber"/>

<button id="smtbxno" onclick="storagecalc">

<img src="images/tick.gif" alt="proceed"/>

</button>

</form>
```

and display it here:

```
<div id="grandtotal">

<p class="calctitles">

Grand Total

</p>

<p id="numberprice">

</p>

</div>
```

Nothing is happening when I enter a value into the textbox and click the button, is this because the button also has jQuery that hides itself and the text box upon clicking? 
If not any suggestions for why it won't work?

Comment: What, if any, error(s) are reported by your JavaScript console?

Comment: The button in the code you gave us has no additional jQuery.

Comment: no errors reported, the jQuery controls various elements, and is activated with .click function. I don't think it will help to post it.

Comment: could it be because the function is before $(document).ready(function()?

Comment: No, that would be OK (and it's even required that the function is available in global scope). But you must post your *complete* document if something interferes, otherwise we won't be able to help you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I hide a text input element with javascript, can other javascript functions still access a value entered into it?

Every piece of javascript that can obtain a reference to the input element (via a variable, with a DOM selector) can access its value. The visibility of that element has no effect on any of those actions. Only if you would detach it from the DOM, other functions could not select it with DOM methods.

---

OK, there are some errors in the document you gave us:

- `<button onclick="storagecalc">` does not execute anything, you will need to call the function: `<button onclick="storagecalc();">`. Only when assigning a listener to the `onclick` *property* with js, the function object needs to be used (`document.getElementById("smtbxno").onclick = storagecalc;`).
- In the function itself, you use a variable `quantity` which is `undefined` (and throws an exception). I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the function but not calling it:

```
<button id="smtbxno" onclick="storagecalc()" ... >...</button>
------------------------------------------^
```

Also, members of the form's elements collection should be referenced by **name**, not by id.

```
var boxno=thediv.elements["boxnumber"];
```

I don't understand why you have a different name and ID, that will confuse IE which, in older versions at least, doesn't know the difference.

Comment: I've rectified the oversight but still nothing happening.. :(

Comment: Which one? Also, a button in a form is, by default, a submit button so the form is being submitted, refreshing the page and possibly disguising the operation of the script.

Comment: But there is no action attached to the button? Could I grab the values from the text input without it being in a form? If so how would I access it? - Changed the name and id to the same thing but still no luck.

Comment: [Buttons in forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) are submit buttons **by default**. If you don't want a submit button, use an input type button. If you aren't submitting the form, don't use one, but they are handy for referencing the controls.

Comment: Thank you, whilst it did not solve the problem I posted, you gave me some very useful information.

Comment: Cool, as long as it was helpful. :-)